# Reescrita de url não funciona no https

Tags: apache, htaccess

Estou com o seguinte problema: 
Meu .htaccess define minha reescrita de URL que funciona perfeitamente quando acesso por http porém quando acesso por https ele informa que a página não foi encontrada. 
Segue abaixo o meu .htaccess.

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?area=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?area=$1&sub=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?area=$1&sub=$2&subitem=$3 [L]
```

Alguém já passou pelo mesmo? Tem alguma ideia de o que pode ser?

Comment: Acho que pode te ajudar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398951/force-ssl-https-using-htaccess-and-mod-rewrite lá tem um exemplo de reescrita com https

Comment: Não é bem isso que eu procuro @RafaelWithoeft . A minha reescrita tem que funcionar para os dois protocolos, o problema é que só está funcionando para o http. No https ele considera que meu arquivo não existe.

Comment: Fábio tente dar uma olhada nesse então: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/http-https-rewriterule-redirect.html na parte onde diz `New HTTPS to HTTP Redirection ^` ele te dá a opção para o uso dos 2;

Comment: @RafaelWithoeft muito obrigado pela ajuda, o htaccess estava correto, o erro estava na configuração do apache.

Comment: Perfeito, que bom que achou a solução.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido, vou deixar a resposta aqui para ajudar quem mais passe por isso.

No apache a configuração do tratamento HTTP estava com AllowOverride all e isso libera a reescrita no diretório que eu preciso. Porém o HTTPS estava configurado como AllowOverride none impedindo assim o funcionamento da reescrita de url.

Ao mudar para AllowOverride all a reescrita passou a funcionar perfeitamente.